# output image in a Kohana 3.2 view

Tags: php, image, view, kohana

I have the following script to output an image to the browser wich works fine.

```
$file_to_output=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/static/imgs/uploads/20110318172207_16.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$raw=imagecreatefromjpeg($file_to_output);

// Output the image
imagejpeg($raw);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($raw);
```

when I put this exact same code in a view its doesn't work anymore and give a bunch of stange characters like this:
    ����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ��C

What do I have to do to make it work in a view?

Comment: Which version of Kohana are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not supposed to put that into a view. All view output is buffered, being returned through a Response object later.

This is all response logics, so your **action** code should look like:

```
$path = DOCROOT.'static/imgs/uploads/20110318172207_16.jpg';

$this->response->headers('content-type',File::mime($path))
    ->body(file_get_contents($path));
```

Comment: Thanks, so I dont use a view at all? I still don't get it to work it outputs an 'Image corrupt or truncated' image. But the file 102kb.

Comment: I works! Thanks again. I had a return in above the next line `<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');`

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be:

```
$path = DOCROOT.'static/imgs/uploads/20110318172207_16.jpg';

// Send file as download
$this->response->send_file($path);

// Send file as inline
$this->response->send_file($path, NULL, array('attachment' => 'inline'));

// Another way to send as inline
$this->response->body(file_get_contents($path));
$this->response->send_file(TRUE, $path);
```

see [Response#send_file](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Response#send_file)

Comment: he's outputting images to browser, not sending them as download

Comment: there are options to send them as attachment or inline using this `send_file` method :)

Comment: I'll edit the code so it shows how to use it with inline images then :)