# Kohana 3.2.0 cannot output an image correctly

Tags: php, kohana

I have read the thread [output image in a Kohana 3.2 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204059/output-image-in-a-kohana-3-2-view), but the code doesn't work on my computer.

I wrote an action that outputs an image to the browser
(If I changed the super class to Controller, it still doesn't work.), the code is like:

```
class Controller_Portal extends Controller_Template {
    public function action_view() {
        $filename = "E:\workspace\myphoto.jpg";

        $this->response->headers('Content-Type', File::mime($filename))
            ->send_headers()  // If I remove this line, It still doesn't work
            ->body(file_get_contents($filename));

        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works after I added `$this->auto_render = FALSE;` in the action and removed the `exit;` at the end.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into this one, you can now accept this answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [send_file()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Response#send_file)

```
$this->response->send_file($filename, NULL, array('inline' => true));
```

After the call of this method no any processing can be done, method calls `exit` when file was sent.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a working, accepted answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204059/output-image-in-a-kohana-3-2-view/), so it's probably worth trying the exact code used there and see if it works.

The only difference seems to be removed the `->send_header()` fragment, but you never know :)

Comment: hello, I have tried to remove the ->send_headers(), the action still doesn't function.

Comment: Fair enough. The only other thing I'd be able to suggest is just quickly echoing `File::mime($filename)` to make sure it's definitely getting the right file. Other than that, over to anyone more familiar with Ko3.2 - I use 3.0 and 2.3

Answer (score 0):

@atma:
Totally correct with send file but:
This is not fully true. You can of course do any processing after the exit is called.
There are several methods. First of all could be an callback given to: register_shutdown_function() the other method would be to create a "post processing class",
which has "function __destruct()" which gets called after the exit is called.

Just my 2 cents :)